# Formatting string (Removing leading zeros)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am newbie to xslt. My requirement is to transform xml file into text file as per the business specifications. I am facing an issue with one of the string formatting issue. Please help me out if you have any idea.

Here is the part of input xml data:
 "0001295"

Expected result to print into text file:
1295

My main issue is to remove leading Zeros. Please share if you have any logic/function.

Comment: I have similar problem, a string with two or more numbers (ex. `hello 002 and 021, bye`), that we can not solve with a trivial *"left trim"* function... But have a solution with XSLT1, since we can use [registered functions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XSLT#Registered_functions) (see answer below).

Answer (score 28):

**Just use this simple expression**:

```
number(.)
```

**Here is a complete example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="t">
      <xsl:value-of select="number(.)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>0001295</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
1295
```

---

**II. Use `format-number()`**

```
format-number(., '#')
```

Answer (score 9):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. If the value is entirely numeric (for example not a CSV line or part of a product code such as ASN0012345) you can convert from a string to a number and back to a string again :

```
string(number($value)).
```

Otherwise just replace the 0's at the start :

```
replace( $value, '^0*', '' )
```

The '^' is required (standard regexp syntax) or a value of 001201 will be replaced with 121 (all zero's removed).

Hope that helps. 
Dave

Comment: Hi Dave,
First of all thanks for your input. Basically I was interested in removing Leading zeros in alphanumeric string. So I used your second solution 
replace( $value, '^0*', '' ). When I use it following error is getting displayed. 'replace' is not a valid XSLT or XPath function. -->replace( $Part, '^0*', '' )<--
. Do you have any idea for the solution. For your information I am using xml Version 1.0.

Comment: Ahh right, replace is XSLT 2.0

Use translate instead and it should work fine :
translate( $value, '^0*', '' )

Comment: OPS, error: `translate` function not process regular expressions (!). See @TimC anwser.  With *XSLT1* the only way to use regex and other good functions (like `trim`) is to enables the use of the caller language (ex. PHP calling XSLT), see ex. [this Wikibook of PHP Programming/XSL/registerPHPFunctions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/XSL/registerPHPFunctions).

Answer (score 7):

Here is one way you could do it in XSLT 1.0.

First, find the first non-zero element, by removing all the zero elements currently in the value

```
<xsl:variable name="first" select="substring(translate(., '0', ''), 1, 1)" />
```

Then, you can find the substring-before this first character, and then use substring-after to get the non-zero part after this

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., substring-before(., $first))" />
```

Or, to combine the two statements into one

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., substring-before(., substring(translate(., '0', ''), 1, 1)))" />
```

So, given the following input

```
<a>00012095Kb</a>
```

Then using the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/a">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., substring-before(., substring(translate(., '0', ''), 1, 1)))" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The following will be output

```
12095Kb
```

Answer (score 3):

As a simple alternative in XSLT 2.0 that can be used with numeric or alpha-numeric input, with or without leading zeros, you might try:

```
replace( $value, '^0*(..*)', '$1' )
```

This works because `^0*` is greedy and `(..*)` captures the rest of the input after the last leading zero. `$1` refers to the captured group.

Note that an input containing only zeros will output `0`.

Comment: This question is tagged `xslt-1.0`

Answer (score 3):

XSLT 2.0
Remove leading zeros from STRING

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace( $value, '^0+', '')"/>
```

Comment: This question is tagged `xslt-1.0`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a recursive template that will remove the leading zeros:

```
<xsl:template name="remove-leading-zeros">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with($text,'0')">
            <xsl:call-template name="remove-leading-zeros">
                <xsl:with-param name="text"
                    select="substring-after($text,'0')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Invoke it like this:

```
 <xsl:call-template name="remove-leading-zeros">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="/path/to/node/with/leading/zeros"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(.) * 1"/>
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

All XSLT1 parser, like the popular [libXML2's module for XSLT](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/), have the [registered functions facility](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XSLT#Registered_functions)... So, we can suppose to use it. Suppose also that the language that call XSLT, is PHP: see [this wikibook about registerPHPFunctions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/XSL/registerPHPFunctions).

---

The build-in PHP function `ltrim` can be used in

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
       xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
       xmlns:fn="http://php.net/xsl">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="test">
       show <xsl:value-of select="fn:function('ltrim',string(.),'0')" />",
   </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Now imagine a little bit more complex problem, to `ltrim` a string with more than 1 number, ex.  `hello 002 and 021, bye`.

The solution is the same: use registerPHPFunctions, except to change the build-in function to a user defined one,

```
function ltrim0_Multi($s) {
    return preg_replace('/(^0+|(?<= )0+)(?=[1-9])/','',$s);
}
```

converts the example into  `hello 2 and 21, bye`.

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="replace($string, '^0+', '')"/>

Comment: Thanks @JaarSingleton. Yes, use of *registerPHPFunctions* only for solve complex problems... The main problem is  the standard XSLT **v1** that was abandoned (there are no intermediary 1.1, 1.2 with grouping functionalities) and the [no-free DOM parser of XSLT v2](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/205580/84349).