# How to remove first three characters from a title using xslt?

Tags: xslt

For example I have a string like "0002187433" from that @0002187433 I need to remove first 3 digits by using `XSLT` and output I should be getting like "2187433".

I have tried like `<xsl:value-of select="substring(0002187433,3,string-length(0002187433)-7)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>` but it is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting string (Removing leading zeros)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801289/formatting-string-removing-leading-zeros)

Comment: "Request you to give me response asap"... LOL

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring('0002187433', 4)" />
```